# Dynamically extract text from webpage using Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract player position from many players' webpages (here's an example for [Malcolm Brogdon](https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/malcolm-brogdon-1.html)). I'm able to extract Malcolm Brogdon's position using the following code:

```
player_id = 'malcolm-brogdon-1'

# Import libraries
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/{}.html".format(player_id)
req = Request(url , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

pos = page_soup.p.find("strong").next_sibling.strip()
pos
```

However, I want to be able to do this in a more dynamic way (that is, to locate "Position:" and then find what comes after). There are other players for which the webpage is structured slightly differently, and my current code wouldn't return position (i.e. [Cat Barber](https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/anthony-cat-barber-1.html)).

I've tried doing something like `page_soup.find("strong", text="Position:")` but that doesn't seem to work.

[image: Malcolm Brogdon's Sports-Reference webpage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the element that contains the text "Position:" and then the next text sibling:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/anthony-cat-barber-1.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

pos = soup.select_one('strong:contains("Position")').find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()
print(pos)
```

Prints:

```
Guard
```

---

EDIT: Another version:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/anthony-cat-barber-1.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

pos = (
    soup.find("strong", text=lambda t: "Position" in t)
    .find_next_sibling(text=True)
    .strip()
)
print(pos)
```

Comment: When I run this code I get the following error: `NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.` Any idea why?

Comment: @Christine you are using old version of BeautifulSoup. Update to the latest.

Comment: @Christine I put also other version, you can try it (maybe it will work with old version of bs4)

Comment: I updated my version because that's probably just a good idea in general. It works great now! Thanks so much. I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer.